# how to create unique_together index using Uniqueconstraints function in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-constraints

official document says: UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future. 
here is my code

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['token','obj'], name='hello')]
```

when i migrate it creates a migrations with message '- Create constraint hello on model helloWorld'. but it is not creating an index on database.

Comment: what database are you using, how do you check if unique constraint is present also show content of your migration and these fields

Comment: At least for Django 3.2.6 and SQLite I can tell there actually is an index created automatically named "sqlite_autoindex_<appname>_<model name>", so no need to create an extra index!

Answer (score 2):

Indexing is done through another `Meta` option: [**`indexes`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    # …

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['token','obj'], name='hello')
        ]
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=('token', 'obj'), condition='TRUE'),
        ]
```

The idea is that being unique together does not per se means you want to index the two (together). Furthermore you can specify for what condition(s) you want to index the fields, by specifing a [**`condition=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/indexes/#condition).

For more information, seee the [*model index reference* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/indexes/).

Comment: it is not creating an unique index. it just create an index

Comment: @Willem Isn't unique constraint implemented same way as index  on database level. That would mean there is no functional difference between so adding index would be overkill

Comment: @iklinac it just create a index. not an unquie index.

Comment: @ashleyparker: well the question is more: does PostgreSQL (or any database) create an unique index if you add a unique constraint. iklinac might be right that this is implied.

Comment: @willem. if i use unique_together=[fields,......] it is creating unique index

Comment: @ashleyparker: I think a workaround is to set `condition=True` in the `Index`. It looks like there is a bug. Perhaps worth creating a Django ticket.

Comment: @ashleyparker: what if you add `condition='TRUE'`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem contidition='TRUE' it says ValueError: Index.condition must be a Q instance.

Comment: @ashleyparker: and `condition=Q(Q())`? It looks like the Django ORM has a small bug...